# How to use corrplot with simple matrices

Tags: r, matrix, r-corrplot

I have a simple 8 by 8 matrix

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(64), nrow=8, ncol=8)
```

How should I transform it to plot it with `library(corrplot)`? Without transformation the error is:

```
corrplot.mixed(M)
```

> Error in corrplot(corr, type = "upper", method = upper, diag = TRUE, tl.pos = tl.pos,  : 
>         The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
>   which I guess would assume that the matrix should be [-1, 1]?

Answer (score 21):

Just indicate that it is not a correlation matrix:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(M, is.corr = FALSE, method = "square")
```

[image]

Comment: What if it is a correlation matrix?

Comment: Then you can do: `corrplot(cor(M))`. This will use a correlation matrix for the M matrix (with pearson method as default).